# "The" for laying emphasis

Tags: emphasis

Is this a correct statement?

"The lion and tiger belong to the cat family."

Or should it be -

"The lion and *the* tiger belong to the cat family."

Comment: What do you mean by "emphasis"? Standard usage is to name *the most important of a pair* first. If you wanted to emphasis "tiger" you'd probably say *The tiger and [the] lion...* Repeating "the" here is mostly just an arbitrary matter of style, which I don't think has any semantic overtones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these statements would be grammatically correct.  However, like @FumbleFingers commented, there is no difference in emphasis; rather, it is a matter of style whether to repeat the article "the."  However, I would generally use the word **both** after the second noun, as in:

> The lion and tiger **both** belong to the cat family.

The word both is not strictly necessary, but I would always use it personally.  The addition of the word both helps to demonstrate that the lion and the tiger are two different entities, and helps to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I think you would add *both* to imply that the lion and the tiger are two different entities, not one, which as you properly added isn't necessary, but helps to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: That's very true...I added it to my answer.